# Usar ILogger com .Net Core 2

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, log, .net-core, entity-framework-core

Estou estudando .Net Core 2 e estou com uma dúvida. Estou querendo logar erro na minha camada Repository e só vi exemplo no Controller. Algum motivo especifico pra isso?

Segue meus códigos:

appsettings.json

```
{
   "ConnectionStrings": {
   "DefaultConnection": "Server=FAYOL\\SQLEXPRESS;Database=Pagamento;Trusted_Connection=True;MultipleActiveResultSets=true"
      },
      "Logging": {
        "IncludeScopes": false,
        "Debug": {
          "LogLevel": {
            "Default": "Warning"
          }
        },
        "Console": {
          "LogLevel": {
            "Default": "Warning"
          }
        }
      }
    }
```

Program.cs

```
public static void Main(string[] args)
{
    BuildWebHost(args).Run();
}


public static IWebHost BuildWebHost(string[] args) =>
  WebHost.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
     .UseStartup<Startup>()
     .ConfigureLogging((hostingContext, logging) =>
     {
                        logging.AddConfiguration(hostingContext.Configuration.GetSection("Logging"));
                        logging.AddConsole();
                        logging.AddDebug();
     })
     .Build();
```

LojaRepository.cs

```
private readonly Contexto _context;
private readonly ILogger _logger;

public LojaRepository(Contexto context, ILogger<LojaRepository> logger)
{
   _context = context;
   _logger = logger;
}

public void Salvar(Loja loja)
{
    _logger.LogInformation("Teste de log para salvar");
}
```

Aonde eu digo qual o nome do arquivo e em que lugar salvar?

Obrigado

Comment: Tem que instalar um pacote que é um tipo de provider que grava em arquivo tipo txt os logs da sua aplicação: https://github.com/fulviocanducci/serilog-extensions-logging-file da uma olhada nesse link!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Você pode usar o Serilog. Com ele você tem várias opções de onde registrar seu log.

Instale os seguintes pacotes NuGet: `Serilog.AspNetCore, Serilog.Sinks.Console` e `Serilog.Sinks.File`

Configure o Serilog no arquivo Program.cs:

```
public class Program
{
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        // Configure Serilog for logging
        Log.Logger = new LoggerConfiguration()
       .MinimumLevel.Debug()
       .MinimumLevel.Override("Microsoft", LogEventLevel.Information)
       .Enrich.FromLogContext()
       .WriteTo.Console()
       .WriteTo.File("logs/log.txt", rollingInterval: RollingInterval.Day)
       .CreateLogger();

        try
        {
            Log.Information("Starting Amplifier web host");
            BuildWebHost(args).Run();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Log.Fatal(ex, "Host terminated unexpectedly");
        }
        finally
        {
            Log.CloseAndFlush();
        }            
    }

    public static IWebHost BuildWebHost(string[] args) =>
        WebHost.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
            .UseStartup<Startup>()
            .UseSerilog() // Replace the default logging provider
            .Build();
}
```

Note que na configuração colocamos o log para ser salvo em um arquivo chamado log.txt na pasta logs e para printar o log no console.

Depois de configurado é só usar:

```
public class TestController : Controller
{
    private readonly ILogger _logger;

    public TestController(ILogger logger)
    {
        _logger = logger;
    }

    public IActionResult Register()
    {
        //Some controller logic...

        _logger.LogInformation("User named {0} created with id: {1}", user.Name, user.Id);
    }
}
```

Para mais alguns detalhes você pode ver o [post que fiz sobre isso em meu blog](https://medium.com/fabridamazio-pt/logging-no-asp-net-core-usando-serilog-6c0afa326b2a)